# PowerShell/GetEnumerator

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a simple question:

Why the program below does not write the whole array `$lines`? It is looping forever. I am really confused..

```
function Get-Current ($enumerator) {
    $line = $enumerator.Current
    return $line
}

$lines = @('a', 'b', 'c')
$enumerator = $lines.GetEnumerator()
$enumerator.Reset()

while ($enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    $line = Get-Current $enumerator
    "$line"     
}
```

Comment: As of PowerShell 7.3.4, things have changed so that this outputs the expected behavior "a`nb`nc`n"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as though the expression:

```
$enumerator
```

unwinds the entire enumerator. For e.g.:

```
PS C:\> $lines = @('a', 'b', 'c')
PS C:\> $enumerator = $lines.GetEnumerator()
PS C:\> $enumerator.Reset()
PS C:\> $enumerator
a
b
c
```

So, when you try to pass your expression to the function, it is rendered invalid. The only workaround I can think of is to pass it as a PSObject like so:

```
function Get-Current ($val) {
    $val.Value.Current
}

$lines = @('a', 'b', 'c')
$enumerator = $lines.GetEnumerator()
$enumerator.Reset()

while ($enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    $line = Get-Current $(get-variable -name enumerator)
    $line
}
```

Comment: PowerShell automatically unwraps arrays and enumerators in many cases.  This is usually pretty handy and time saving, but sometimes it causes problems as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why MoveNext never returns false. This works

```
$lines = @('a', 'b', 'c')
$enumerator = $lines.GetEnumerator()

while ($enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    $enumerator.Current
}
```

Comment: Ok, I know. I would never used those statements to simply iterate an array. The snippet is just an illustration.

So my question still is why the function call "damage" the enumerator.

Comment: @Marek Tried to rename the parameter, tried to wrap in PsObject but nothing worked. Pretty tricky behaviour :)