# Using GetEnumerator in PowerShell on IEnumerable implemented using C# yield return

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, ienumerable, yield-return

I have an API that returns `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IEnumerable`), which is internally implemented in C# using `yield return`.

A trivial example:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Enumerate()
    {
        yield return 1;
    }
}
```

In PowerShell, I cannot call `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` on the enumerable returned by the method `Enumerate()`:

```
$cls = New-Object Class1

$enumerable = $cls.Enumerate()

Write-Host $enumerable.GetType()

$enumerator = $enumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

It fails with:

> Cannot find an overload for "GetEnumerator" and the argument count: "0".

The `$enumerable.GetType()` returns expected:

> Class1+d__0

An identical code in C# works as expected.

---

If the method is implemented using a plain `return`:

```cs
return new[] { 1 };
```

then there's no problem in PowerShell.

---

Why PowerShell does not see the `GetEnumerator()`?

*I have found this somewhat related question: [PowerShell/GetEnumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2972615/850848), but it does not really give me the answer/solution (or I do not see it).*

---

To explain, why I want to use the `IEnumerator`, instead of using PowerShell `foreach`: I want to process the enumerable using parallel threads started using `Start-ThreadJob`. And the enumeration is lazy and time intensive. So collecting the results to some container prior to the enumeration would have a performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the compiler-generated `IEnumerable<T>` type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator<T>` [explicitly](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5lQDMmM6AwugN7Lq2bFaEA8AlgHYAuAfOgLIAUASio06YrHEwB2dHHxIxAX2SKgA):

```
private sealed class <M>d__0 : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable, ...
{
    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Late-bound languages typically have problems with explicitly implemented interfaces in .NET: after all your enumerator is of type `<M>d__0`, and that type implements two different `GetEnumerator()` methods which return different things.

(It doesn't matter that it got that instance of `<M>d__0` by calling a method which returned an `IEnumerable<int>`: late-bound languages forget all about that bit of type information).

The language needs to provide special syntax to let you say which interface's version of `GetEnumerator()` you want to call. IronPython for example would [let you say something like](https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#id48):

```py
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[int].GetEnumerator(enumerator)
```

I'm not aware of any PowerShell syntax to do the same (and my searching didn't find anything), instead people [seem to be using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19250387/1086121):

```
[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[int]].GetMethod("GetEnumerator").Invoke($enumerable, $Null)
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the @canton7's answer: Instead of using the reflection in PowerShell, you might want modify the C# code to use an implicit implementation. If you want to keep using the `yield return`, you can add a wrapper class that implements the interface implicitly on top of the generated explicit implementation.

You need to choose what interface you want to implement implicitly, the `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`. For a use in PowerShell, it probably does not matter. The code below implements `IEnumerable<T>` implicitly.

```
internal class ImplicitEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;

    public ImplicitEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Enumerate()
    {
        return new ImplicitEnumerable<int>(DoEnumerate());
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> DoEnumerate()
    {
        yield return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the reflection method didn't work for me.

But I managed to enumerate through the IEnumerable by using LINQ and the method ToArray(), like so:

```
$array = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray($enumerable)
```

I think the reason why reflection did not work is because the member items of the IEnumerable in my case, were objects (of a custom class), and not base classes like [int] or [string]

Comment: Well, that an obvious solution, that does not answer the question, which says: *"And the enumeration is lazy and time intensive. So collecting the results to some container prior to the enumeration would have a performance penalty."*